# yii : how to display the different menu(s) by user role?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Q : How can I show display different menu(s) by user role?

Description : the app has many roles. e.g HR manager, Account Manager, Operating Manager, Employee, Operator, ...., etc. I used rights and yii-user modules to create those roles. Those roles have different functions. So the app will show different menu for different user's role after logged in. Now, I can lock the function for different user. e.g when HR manger logged in, he/she can't route to other function of user role. But I don't know how to show the HR Menu for Hr Manager, only.

I am not a newbie for yii. but I'm a newbie for those modules (rihgts and yii-user).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control) you can set the 'visible' param of CMenu items depending on the users privileges, for example;

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'items'=>array(
        array(
            'label'=>'Home',
            'url'=>array('site/index'),
        ),
        array(
            'label'=>'HR',
            'url'=>array('/hr/index'),
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('hr')
        ),
        array(
            'label'=>'Accounts',
            'url'=>array('/account/index'),
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('account')
        ),
        array(
            'label'=>'Operations',
            'url'=>array('/operations/index'),
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('operations')
        ),
    ),
);
```

This way users will only be able to see the items in the menu if they have access privileges for that area.

[**EDIT**]

As per simaremare's comment below, you can force caching of this query beyond the current request by extending `CWebUser`. Firstly, set your user to run through your new class (we'll call it `TWebUser`), so in your main.php config file;

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        ...
        'class'=>'TWebUser',
        ...
    ),
    ...
),
```

Now we need to create `TWebUser` to cache these beyond the current request (which is what `CWebUser` does ([source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L801)):

```
class TWebUser extends CWebUser
{
    private $_access=array();

    public function checkAccess($operation,$params=array(),$allowCaching=true)
    {
        if($allowCaching && $params===array() && isset($this->_access[$operation]))
            return $this->_access[$operation];

        $cache = Yii::app()->session['checkAccess'];
        if($allowCaching && !$this->getIsGuest() && isset($cache[$operation]) && time() - $cache[$operation]['t'] < 1800)
        {
            $checkAccess = $cache[$operation]['p'];
        } else {
            $checkAccess = Yii::app()->getAuthManager()->checkAccess($operation,$this->getId(),$params);

            if($allowCaching && !$this->getIsGuest())
            {
                $access = isset($cache) ? $cache : array();
                $access[$operation] = array('p'=>$checkAccess, 't'=>time());
                Yii::app()->session['checkAccess'] = $access;
            }
        }

        return $this->_access[$operation] = $checkAccess;
    }
}
```

Now your access results will be set for the whole session. This does mean that if you edit the RBAC permissions for a given account, they'll have to log out and log in again to see the new changes reflected in the browser.

I hope that helps! I'm sure I found this workaround from someone else (probably on SO), but I can't find the original post to give them credit.

Comment: this will do query everytime doing checkAccess(), this seems not efficient.

Comment: Hi @simaremare, that's a good point, the default user class (`CWebUser`) only caches these results for the current request, I've added an update that's a bit more efficient.

Comment: well explained, thanks. It gives me more idea about customizing RBAC.

Answer (score 1):

You would wrap an if-statement around the menu-items that you may or may not want to show.

In the if-statement, you would have to test whether the user qualifies to see your menu-items.

For example:

```
<?php if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest): ?>

  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'items'=>array(
  array(
        'label'=>'this menu item visible only for Guests (not logged in)', 
        'url'=>array('/site/index')),
      ),
    )); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank for you help. Yes, I knew this isGuest. but I've different role name at authitem tbl, e.g HR Manager. My problem is I don't know how to check HR Manager role. I tried isHRManager, but it is not working. And I tried Authenticated as isAuthenticated, but it is not working also. How can I check other role as isGuest?